# rem of media queries vs rem of anything else

Tags: html, css, media-queries, language-lawyer, font-size

As per the [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#rem) about rem values:

> Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element. When
> specified on the font-size property of the root element, the rem units
> refer to the property’s initial value

However, I can use `@media` queries even to alter the `font-size` for the `:root` selector, and I can use a quantity in `rem`s as the breakpoint.

So to me it looks like the `@media` query *"reads"* the value of `1rem` to set the breakpoint, but if theres a `:root {}` ruleset in it, it also *"sets"* the value of `1rem`, leading to a cycle in the definition.

What am I missing?

To give an example, in the snippet below, if you resize the window around the breakpoint ([same snippet on JSFiddle, where resizing of the panels is a bit easier](https://jsfiddle.net/Enrico89/5gbxmLyv/9/)), you'll see that the size of the ellipse (which has `width: 50rem;`) changes, which means that the meaning of `1rem` changes when we cross the breakpoint, which means that we truly switch from `:root { font-size: 0.5em; }` to `:root { font-size: 2rem; }` across the breakpoint.

***Which ultimately means, I understand, that we are successfully changing the computed value of `font-size` on the `:root` element.***

If that's the case, how is it even possible to use `rem`s for the breakpoint of the media query?

Observing the result of the snippet below, I'd say that the breakpoint happens at the same viewport width regardless of how `font-size` is changed in `:root {}` rulesets.

What part of the standard explains what I'm observing?

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
.shape {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

@media (min-width: 50rem) {
  .shape {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  :root {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
</div>
ciao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the same specification:

> When used **outside the context of an element** (such as in media queries), these units refer to the computed font metrics corresponding to the **initial** values of the font property.

So `50rem` is simply `50*16px = 800px`

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.5rem;
}
.shape {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 10rem;
}

@media (min-width: 50rem) {
  .shape {
    background-color: blue;
  }  
  :root {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .shape {
    outline:10px solid green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
</div>
```